# is it ill-advised to run CruiseControl.NET on the same box as the production server

Tags: build-process, cruisecontrol.net

for very low-volume bandwidth site in production with iis7/win08 - should i have concerns (re: overall system stability) about installing CruiseControl.NET as a build server implementation?

Comment: It's generally ill-advised to mix production and non-production _anything_.

Comment: ;) understood. I'm looking for the 'omgNo' level of ill-advisedment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Anything that goes wrong with your CI builds can (and probably will) impact your production server.

That being said, it's really your risk-management decision...

Answer (score 1):

CruiseControl.NET just launch other tools to execute the build, and it can change over time (version, tools, framework ..).

So, IMHO, you should really be carefull about it as mentionned by John W.
From our experience, **it is better to separate it** at least in a Virtual machine.